# Add Search Layout from Custom Object to Change Set

Tags: change-set, search-layout

How can I add a search layout to a change set for a **CUSTOM** object? I know there is a question out there for standard objects, so not sure if the same logic applies to custom objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you add the entire object, the search layout is automatically added to the change set. Do you not see that?

Sridhar

Answer (score 0):

Sridhar is correct. When you move objects, layouts should automatically move. However, I am not sure about list views. You may have to move them independently.

[Flosum](http://www.flosum.com) is a great tool for [Salesforce migration](http://www.flosum.com). It automatically moves the layouts for you.

Comment: Quick correction: When you move objects, the search layouts move automatically. Page Layouts, however, can be moved independently.  List Views are also part of the entire object. However, the metadata API gives you the option to move list view separately as well.

Answer (score 0):

Created objects and tested 2 scenarios:

1. Created object and allow to launch tab for this custom object. **`search layout`** option can be seen with other options.
2. Created custom object and didn't allowed to launch tab here **`search layout`** option is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the entire object to move your search layout changes. Since you are using change sets, just add the entire object. This would have ben true even in the case if you were using metadata api - ANT etc. Salesforce does not have a metadata equivalent component for Search Layouts and they can only be moved along as object metadata. This is not the case with similar components like custom field, validation rules, list views etc. Hope this helps.